# php bin/console make:entity inside a bundle

Tags: php, command-line-interface, bundle, symfony4

I'm using symfony 4

I've builded a bundle for a reusable application and i wanna continue to use php cli command make:entity.

How may i to use it for my specific bundle's folder destination ?

Thx!

Comment: Could you try that? ( php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App\CoreBundle ) OR ( php bin/console make:entity --regenerate CoreBundle )

Comment: @DenizAktürk, here the description of --regenerate option : Instead of adding new fields, simply generate the methods (e.g. getter/setter) for existing fields.

I just wanna use the make:entity on an other directory (into my bundle's folder)

Comment: Did not you create a table in your database? you are trying to create a table with this command. make:entity

Comment: I've already created tables with make:entity command, before bundle creation. Like you know, this command can add some new fields too, with their getters, setters and annotations.

Comment: Maybe if you examine it, it might be more descriptive. https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Comment: Your first command --regenerate works, (i had to put double slash between namespace path), but this functionality just regenerates the Setters/Getters.
I would like to use make:entity to add new fields into my DB.

I tried `php bin/console make:entity App\\MyBundle\\Entity\\MyEntity` but symfony create me a new Entity into main src folder.

Comment: I know they've been doing them arrangements recently, so their support may be limited right now. Maybe it works if old commands are working. https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_entity.html

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work, i've got this message : Command "generate:doctrine:entity" is not defined.

I hope it will work soon !

Thx a lot for your patience and your investigations !

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution, it's pretty simple.

1: 
`php bin/console make:entity`

2: when Symfony ask the class name, enter namespace of Entity class of your bundle:

`\App\Author\BundleName\Entity\Class`

If it's working, Symfony does not make a new Entity class.

Cheers !